# pahole C++11 support?

Tags: c++, c++11, pahole

I don't know why but my copy of `pahole` happens to not work with any binary compiled in C++11, it works with C++03, but not with C++11: there is C++11 support in pahole ?

the output is something like

```
die__process_class: tag not supported (template_type_parameter)!
die__process_unit: DW_TAG_unspecified_type (0x3b) @ <0x1a26> not handled!
pahole: No debugging information found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to be a well known bug.

See:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=962571

I tried to build from git

```
git clone https://github.com/acmel/dwarves.git
cd dwarves
cmake ..
make
./pahole <myprog>
```

The git version works for me!

Comment: Don't use that repo, it is completely out of date (when writing this comment) use https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/devel/pahole/pahole.git instead.